# How to retrieve the table name with SubSonic 3?

Tags: subsonic3

Whit ol' good SubSonic 2 I was able to retrieve the name of the table I was querying:

.Schema.TableName

Now that I switched to SubSonic 3 I can't find any way to achieve the same goal.

I tend to avoid to hardcode the name of the table in the che source code, so if I change it the compiler throw me an exception.

(Note: yes, I'm using the new 'linq-like' syntax for most of the queries, but I dealing with a complex one and I think is better to follow the old manner).

Comment: Is there anybody out there? :)

Comment: anyway..I have changed the .tt file and put the struct code to generate the table names.

Answer (score 0):

Put following into structs.tt and you have Tables class ready with tables. You can use it like subsonic 2.0 that is Table.TableName.

```
 public class Tables
       {
           <#  foreach(var tbl in tables){
            if(!ExcludeTables.Contains(tbl.Name))
            {
            #>
                public static string <#=tbl.CleanName#> = "<#=tbl.Name#>";
            <#
            }
            }
            #>
       }
```